# Operator is an isometry iff |det| is 1

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, isometry

$V$ is a finite dimensional real inner product space where $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $\|Tv\|\leq\|v\|$ $\forall v\in V$. 
Prove that $\left|\det T\right|=1 \iff T$ is an isometry. 
My question is not for a proof of this but whether the following argument works.
I can use the theorem that $T$ is an isometry iff there exists an orthonormal basis of $V$ such that its matrix is block-diagonal with each block either of the form $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$ or a $1\times 1$ block of either $-1$ or $1$. Then determinant of this diagonal matrix is must be $\pm 1$, and so $\left|\det T\right|=1$.
I believe this should prove the question for a generic operator $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ so we do not have to use the fact that $\|Tv\|\leq\|v\|$ $\forall v\in V$ and the answer should still be correct. 
I know there are ways to solve this using $\|Tv\|\leq\|v\|$ but am specifically wondering if my reasoning above works, which I believe it should since if it is true for any real operator, then it is true with this restriction.

Comment: You are right.  If $T$ is an isometry, then already $||Tv|| = ||v||$ for all $v \in V$, so the condition $||Tv|| \leq ||v||$ is redundant.

Comment: Your proof looks correct. The assumption $||Tv|| \leq ||v||$ is needed for the converse of what you proved.

Comment: @D_S : If the difference between $||v||$ and $\|v\|$ is not conspicuous enough for you, look at the difference between $||u|| ||v||$ and $\|u\|\|v\|. \qquad$

Comment: @paulblartmathcop : $\qquad \uparrow \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy they look the same to me?

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& ||u|| ||v|| \\ {} \\
& \|u\|\|v\|
\end{align}
$$
@D_S : You mean these two lines above $\,\,\,\uparrow\,\,\,$ look identical to you? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm seeing the same thing twice

Comment: @D_S : In the first one the four vertical slashes between $u$ and $v$ have equal amounts of space between them. In the second, there is less space between the first and second and between the third and fourth than between the second and third. I'm surprised that that is not conspicuous to you even when they are juxtaposed like this.

Comment: I bet it's your computer.  Do you use a normal browser like Opera?